# Cannot call DriveApp from Google sheet via onEdit() trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have noticed that I can execute calls to SpreadsheetApp using an onEdit() trigger until I make a call to DriveApp in which case no calls to the sheet after that are executed. But all lines of code are executed when I when i run onEdit() from within the script file. Wonder if anyone has overcome this obstacle. A code exammple can be created by running the code from this link:

https://gist.github.com/mesgarpour/07317e81e9ee2b3f1699

It runs fine when executed from within the script file by choosing Run => listFolers();

But if I try to trigger it from the spreadsheet itself by adding:

```
function onEdit() {
  listFolers();
}
```

and then make a change to any cell on the sheet, it doesn't execute.
Is this a bug in GAS? Has anyone been able to call DriveApp code using an onEdit() trigger and successfully write the results to the active sheet?

Comment: Is it an [Installed onEdit() Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)? Sounds like you are using the [Simple onEdit() Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)  which runs with fewer permissions, which may be the reason it doesn't execute

Comment: (Welcome to SO! (You duplicated `when i` and an `m` in `exammple`.) Your post may be easier to grasp if you make code snippets like `onEdit()` stand out enclosing them in `\`\`` "backticks".)

Comment: It's a Simple onEdit() Trigger. I will check out the duplicate an go from there. Thanks everyone!